# Replacing HDD with a smaller SSD

Tags: partitioning, gparted, hardware, clone

I have a dual boot system (Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7 64 bit).

I boot from a HDD that contains both operating systems and use another 1tb HDD for data.

I want to replace the HDD containing the OS's with a 240gb SSD so I need to shrink the partitions so they'll fit.

Can someone give me an easy way to do this? Is there something I can use which will do the trick?

[image]

Comment: You screenshot shows Windows only ??

Comment: You cannot clone partitions from different drives to a single one and expect the dual-boot to work.

Comment: Both are on the same drive

Comment: The screeshot above shows Windows only, one single NTFS partition.

Comment: I've updated the screenshot

Comment: So, you have **2** physical drives. Ubuntu is on `sda` and Windows in `sdb`. My comment above still stands.

Comment: You need to update this question, your post says 1HDD with 2 OS but you screenshot shows 2 HDD with 1 OS each and then you insist in comments it on one HDD? Without this information, your question is unanswerable and will be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an overview of what you need to do.

**NOTE - HERE I AM ASSUMING THAT `sda1` IS YOUR UBUNTU PARTITION AND `sdb1` IS YOUR WINDOWS PARTITION AND `sdc` IS YOUR SSD. WHEN WORKING IN A DIFFERENT ENVIRONMENT CHECK IF THE NAMES ARE SAME**

- First divide your SSD into 2 partitions - one for Ubuntu, another for Windows.
- Note the sizes of the partitions.
- Next, shrink your current Windows and current Ubuntu partitions to the same size as that of your newer partitions using `Gparted`
- Create a live disk and then boot into it.
- Within the booted CD/DVD, clone the Ubuntu partition on HDD to the SSD using `sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdc1 bs=2M` Here, I have assumed that you are going to install Ubuntu on first partition of your SSD. (This is going to take a long time depending on the data in your HDD)**(Again check the partition names before running)**
- In a similar way, clone the Windows partition to the SSD using `sudo dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/dev/sdc2 bs=2M`.
- Next, edit the `fstab` of the cloned Ubuntu partition located at `/etc/fstab` of the new partition as required. (Especially, remove the swap line If you won't have the older HDDs plugged in at boot).  If you do plan to use the older HDDs, you must either assign new GUIDs to the partitions(using Gparted) or reformat the HDDs.
- Finally, reinstall GRUB to SSD.

Comment: Do upvote the answer if it helped you.